# Blur content of AVPlayerLayer

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Is there a way to blur the content being displayed in a AVPlayerLayer? 
The content is a streamed asset (m3u8) so no option for AVAssetReader etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next solution to get image:

```
CIImage *snaphotImage = nil;
AVPlayerItem *item = ((AVPlayerLayer*)view.layer).player.currentItem;
if (item.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)
{
    AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset *)item.asset;
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    CGImageRef thumb = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:((AVPlayerLayer*)view.layer).player.currentTime
                                              actualTime:NULL
                                                   error:NULL];
    snapshotImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:thumb];
    CGImageRelease(thumb);
}
```

And then apply blur to it:

```
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur" 
                              keysAndValues:@"inputRadius", @9.0,
                                            @"inputImage", snapshotImage, nil];
CIImage *resultImage = [filter outputImage];
UIImage *resultUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:resultImage];
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Simply blurring a single snapshot of the video.